# What makes the network request and watches the Timer till it gets done?

Tags: javascript, promise, concurrency, event-loop

Javascript is single threaded, all code and the event loop itself run on the single thread.

So once the engine comes across a fetch request, let's say the event loop takes in this task, makes this request, and pushes the fetch callback to the task queue. Then it goes on to complete other tasks.

My question is, if the Javascript is single threaded, who tells the event loop that the network request is done and time has come to do the callback task associated with it? Because if everything is happening in a single thread, there are no resources left for JS to do countdown of timers/keep track of when the network requests are done. The only way it can happen in a single thread is if there is a phase when it blocks everything while it polls for any completed Timeouts/network requests.

But even if there was a poll phase, then who actually counts the timers's delay in setTimeout and setInterval, if main thread is busy doing other tasks?

Comment: JS is not single-threaded and your question shows why. This statement has simply never been true. A more correct one is that *most* code written by you as a programmer will run in a single thread. That's not all of JS, however, and you can also opt-into multi-threaded execution.

Comment: @VLAZ so you are telling me there is another thread which counts down timers?

Comment: For a timer implementation, you don't need to implement it as a countdown. Record the expected end time and just check against it. However, whether another thread does it would be an implementation detail. With the JS event loop you don't *need* that. Since a timer can't trigger during the run-to-completion cycle anyway, It could simply be checked between event loop iterations and any timers that should have triggered could be added to the queue. I'm not sure what the actual implementation is but it can vary as there no "the" implementation. V8 and SpiderMonkey are different ones.

Comment: The `fetch` specifics are not run in javascript.  (or at least, based on comment above, not in *your* javascript).   fetch is executed by the browser.  In the same way when you click the mouse, the browser takes that event and passes it to (your) javascript - when the browser has completed the fetch it takes that event and passes it to (your) javascript.  The "javascript is single threaded" is a useful paradigm as when the browser gives you those events, your code can't do anything with it if it's already busy doing something else.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put: browsers aren't written in JS and (modern) browsers do use A LOT of processes and threads (on my Google Chrome it's already 7 processes just to render the `chrome://new-tab-page`, each spawning about 20 threads).

So while your JS script will run in a single threaded manner, your browser won't, and the JS execution is only a small part of what the event-loop will do. Most of it can and will be delegated to the many helper processes.

Comment: Okay understood! Any documentation regarding this?

Comment: This is all implementation details, so each implementation will have its own doc. For Chromium you can use this doc as an entrance: https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/inter-process-communication/